# I do not get an answer when looking for higher / lower records than the current date

Tags: mongodb

I'm using robomongo to perform a search. I want to obtain the records that the "FECHA_INICIO" field is greater than or equal to today's date.

```
{
 "_id" : ObjectId("5bda1145b82d4c21a8e56890"),
 "COD_TRAFO" : "N42001",
 "NIU" : "334099968",
 "FECHA_INICIO" : "2018-012-29",
 "FECHA_FIN" : "2018-11-10",
 "HORA_INICIO" : "9:00",
 "HORA_FIN" : "16:00",
 "ESTADO" : "ABIERTO",
 "ORDEN_OP" : "693583"
}
```

[image]
[image]

but with this query:

```
db.getCollection('mycollection').find( {"FECHA_INICIO":{ $gte: new Date("YYYY-mm-dd") }}  )
```

I do not get results, what am I doing wrong? Thank you